# Fractional ideals of the complex ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I'm confused on how to find all fractional ideals of $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-1}$. By their definition, fractional ideals should be contained in the quotient field of the integral domain, but I'm unclear how this would occur. Would all the fractional ideals simply be $\{\frac{n}{m}|n,m\in\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-1}\}$? How do I exclude the cases where $\frac{n}{m}$ can be reduced to an element of the domain (as opposed to a fraction)?

Comment: Note that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-1})$ has class number $1$, so all fractional ideals are principal.

Comment: Because $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a principal ideal domain, the fractional $\Bbb{Z}[i]$-ideals of $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ are its subsets of the form $\frac{a}{b} \Bbb{Z}[i]=\frac{(a)}{b}$ with $a,b\in \Bbb{Z}[i]-0$ and $(a,b)=(1)$. For other number fields it will be $\frac{I}{n}$ where $I$ is a non-zero $O_K$-ideal and $n\in \Bbb{Z}-0$.

Comment: @reuns Is the gcd condition enough? By definition, the fractional ideal also has to be closed under addition. How would I deal with $\frac{1+i}{2+i}$, which is in the fractional ideal, summed with $\frac{1}{2+i}$, also in the fractional ideal? (or am I misunderstanding the definition)

Comment: They are both in the fractional ideal $\frac1{2+i}\Bbb{Z}[i]=\{ \frac{u+iv}{2+i},(u,v)\in \Bbb{Z}\}$. And $(a,b)$ is the generalization of the $\gcd$, it is the ideal $aO_K+bO_K$, when $O_K$ is a euclidean domain (thus a PID) it is the principal ideal generated by the $\gcd$ of $a,b$.

Comment: @reuns No, I mean that for when I add $\frac{1+i}{2+i}+\frac{1}{2+i}=1$. 1 is not a fraction, right? Is it still allowed in the ideal?

Comment: $1=(2+i)/(2+i)$

Comment: Yes, so is 1 in the ideal? 1 is not a fraction.

Comment: come on $(2+i)/(2+i)$ is in $\{ \frac{u+iv}{2+i},(u,v)\in \Bbb{Z}\}$

Comment: @reuns sorry haha just got it. not sure why I was so confused over the definition. thank you!